# How to use variable that have value outside the code block

Tags: ios, swift

What im trying to do is print this (Output : Western Australia)

```
self.stateName = state["ProvinceStateName"]
```

To

```
detailAddressArr = ["\(userData!["AddressLine1"] as! String)", "\(userData!["AddressLine2"] as! String)", "\(userData!["City"] as! String)", "\(userData!["PostalCode"] as! String)", self.stateName, "\(userData!["CountryCode"] as! String)"]
```

But when run, it return nothing.

Here is my code

```
class myProfileViewController: BaseViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var profileTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImg: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bigIDLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLbl: UILabel!

    let personalArr = ["Salutation", "Given Name", "Family Name", "Date of Birth", "Nationality", "Mobile", "Passport"]
    var detailPersonalArr = [String]()

    let addressArr = ["Street 1", "Street 2", "City", "Post Code", "State", "Country"]
    var detailAddressArr = [String]()

    var stateName: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupMyProfileButton()
        self.navigationItem.title = "My Profile"
        showHUD()
        let userInfo = defaults.objectForKey("userInfo")
        bigIDLbl.text = "BIG ID : \(userInfo!["CustomerNumber"] as! String)"
        userNameLbl.text = "\((userInfo!["FirstName"] as! String).capitalizedString) \((userInfo!["LastName"] as! String).capitalizedString)"

        let userData = defaults.objectForKey("userData")

        let countryCode = userData!["CountryCode"] as! String

        let stateCode = userData!["ProvinceStateCode"] as! String

        AirAsiaBigProvider.request(.GetState(countryCode)) { (result) in

            switch result {
            case .Success(let successResult):
                do {

                    let json = try JSON(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(successResult.data, options: .MutableContainers))

                    if json["Status"].string == "OK"{
                        self.hideHUD()
                        let stateList = json["StateList"].arrayObject!

                        for state in stateList {
                            let newStateCode = state["ProvinceStateCode"] as! String

                            if newStateCode == stateCode {
                                print(state["ProvinceStateName"])
                                self.stateName = state["ProvinceStateName"] as! String
                            }
                        }


                    }else if json["Status"].string == "Error"{
                        self.hideHUD()
                        showErrorMessage("\(json["Message"].string!)")
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    self.hideHUD()
                    showErrorMessage("Unable to connect the server")
                }
            case .Failure(let failureResult):
                self.hideHUD()
                showErrorMessage(failureResult.nsError.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

        detailPersonalArr = ["\(userData!["Title"] as! String)", "\(userData!["FirstName"] as! String)", "\(userData!["LastName"] as! String)", "\(userData!["DOB"] as! String)", "\(userData!["Nationality"] as! String)", "\(userData!["MobilePhone"] as! String)", "\(userData!["PID"] as! String)"]
        detailAddressArr = ["\(userData!["AddressLine1"] as! String)", "\(userData!["AddressLine2"] as! String)", "\(userData!["City"] as! String)", "\(userData!["PostalCode"] as! String)", self.stateName, "\(userData!["CountryCode"] as! String)"]

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch(section) {
        case 0:
            return "Personal Info"
        case 1:
            return "Address"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return personalArr.count
        case 1:
            return addressArr.count
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = profileTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomProfileTableViewCell
            cell.title.text = personalArr[indexPath.row]
            cell.detail.text = detailPersonalArr[indexPath.row]
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = profileTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomProfileTableViewCell
            cell.title.text = addressArr[indexPath.row]
            cell.detail.text = detailAddressArr[indexPath.row]
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
            return cell
        }
        fatalError("Unexpected section \(indexPath.section)")
    }

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        print("User Login")
    }
    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("User Logged Out")
    }

    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are printing stateName when it's value is "". block is executed asynchronously after waiting for the request's response and the lines after the the block are executing immediately without waiting. I think all you have to do is to move the print line inside the code block or use property observer to print the stateName every time it changes

suggestion1: Move the print line statement

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupMyProfileButton()
    self.navigationItem.title = "My Profile"
    showHUD()
    let userInfo = defaults.objectForKey("userInfo")
    bigIDLbl.text = "BIG ID : \(userInfo!["CustomerNumber"] as! String)"
    userNameLbl.text = "\((userInfo!["FirstName"] as! String).capitalizedString) \((userInfo!["LastName"] as! String).capitalizedString)"

    let userData = defaults.objectForKey("userData")

    let countryCode = userData!["CountryCode"] as! String

    let stateCode = userData!["ProvinceStateCode"] as! String

    AirAsiaBigProvider.request(.GetState(countryCode)) { (result) in

        switch result {
        case .Success(let successResult):
            do {

                let json = try JSON(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(successResult.data, options: .MutableContainers))

                if json["Status"].string == "OK"{
                    self.hideHUD()
                    let stateList = json["StateList"].arrayObject!

                    for state in stateList {
                        let newStateCode = state["ProvinceStateCode"] as! String

                        if newStateCode == stateCode {
                            print(state["ProvinceStateName"])
                            self.stateName = state["ProvinceStateName"] as! String
                        }
                    }



    //MOVE PRINT INSIDE THE BLOCK
    detailPersonalArr = ["\(userData!["Title"] as! String)", "\(userData!["FirstName"] as! String)", "\(userData!["LastName"] as! String)", "\(userData!["DOB"] as! String)", "\(userData!["Nationality"] as! String)", "\(userData!["MobilePhone"] as! String)", "\(userData!["PID"] as! String)"]
    detailAddressArr = ["\(userData!["AddressLine1"] as! String)", "\(userData!["AddressLine2"] as! String)", "\(userData!["City"] as! String)", "\(userData!["PostalCode"] as! String)", self.stateName, "\(userData!["CountryCode"] as! String)"]

                }else if json["Status"].string == "Error"{
                    self.hideHUD()
                    showErrorMessage("\(json["Message"].string!)")
                }
            }
            catch {
                self.hideHUD()
                showErrorMessage("Unable to connect the server")
            }
        case .Failure(let failureResult):
            self.hideHUD()
            showErrorMessage(failureResult.nsError.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Suggestion2: use property observers

```
var stateName: String?{
    didSet{
        print("State name is \(stateName)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion 1:
New error occur (Index is out of range) when try to print detailAddressArr.

Suggestion 2:
the statename return nil